# Taylor coefficients for $\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)$

Tags: calculus, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

Could you show that in a right neighbourhood of $x=0$
$$\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Gamma(x)\zeta(x)$$

behaves like $(-1)^n \zeta (-1)+1$ when  $n\to \infty$?

Comment: As given, surely this can't hold, since $\Gamma$ has a simple pole at $0$ and $\zeta(0) \neq 0$, so the $n$th derivative has an $(n+1)$th order pole and so diverges at $x=0$?

Comment: I completely agree with Chappers, in order to have an analytic function in a neighbourhood of zero we have to replace $\Gamma(x)\zeta(x)$ with $\Gamma(x)\zeta(x)\color{red}{+\frac{1}{2x}}$.