# What's special about $\zeta(x)\Gamma(x/2+1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I found this when playing with [complex function plotter](https://samuelj.li/complex-function-plotter/) (just enter `zeta(z)*gamma(z/2+1)`).

This eliminates all trivial zeroes of Riemann zeta function, does not create any new singularity, and also the resulting graph (especially along the negative real axis) "looks really smooth".

Thus, I think there must be something special.
But within my search for this, little is obtained.
The closest match I've found is at [Taylor coefficients for $\zeta(x)\Gamma(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206598/taylor-coefficients-for-zetax-gammax) where they're multiplied together but no coefficient on argument is present.

Wolframalpha doesn't give valuable idea either. It even [refuses](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=local+minima&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22local+minima%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22LocalMinimizeCalculator%22%2C+%22curvefunction%22%7D+-%3E%221%2F%28zeta%28x%29*gamma%28x%2F2%2B1%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22LocalMinimizeCalculator%22%2C+%22domain%22%7D+-%3E%22-20%3Cx%3C-16%22) to find the local minima for $\frac 1 {\zeta(x)\Gamma(x/2+1)}$.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function). (Riemann Xi function)

Comment: $\Gamma(z)$ has no zeros but has simple poles at $z=0,-1,2,\dots$, which explains why the Gamma factor cancels out all the trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$.